# Oracle Apex.Stop a page unload(when clicked on a navigable link) if there are any unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm currently using oracle apex. I created a wizard progress list for my page with the labels in the list as navigable links. But when the user clicks on these links to navigate to another page i need to ask the user if he's sure as there are unsaved changes, probably using `apex.message.confirm()`. 
I made it navigable by using `href="my_link"` in the list entry label while creating list in shared components. I know if i add `onClick="my_function();"`i can direct add functionality to that link.But where to add this javascript function at the application level?
How do i do that? any ideas?

Note : I cant use warn on unsaved changes option at the page level. Because iam submitting the values in my page to the db through dynamic action(pl/sql code). So even after clicking on save and inserting data into DB, when i try to navigate to other page it will show warning on unsaved changes. I cant use submit page on click of save button as it is refreshing the whole page and it is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `onClick ="my_function();"` in the name provided while filling in the list entry label in the shared components for list , you can define what needs to be done when clicked on the link.`"my_function"` can then be declared at the page level in the `function and global variable declaration` section.
For example:

```
<a href="#" onClick="my_function('28');">&F300_LABEL_TEXT.</a>
```

will be the list entry label at the shared components! 
and in the `function and global variable declaration` section at the page level.

```
    function my_function(page){
        if (apex.page.isChanged() == true)
          {apex.message.alert("there  are unsaved changes"); 
       else{apex.navigation.redirect("f?p="+$v('pFlowId')+":"+page+":"+$v("pInstance")+"::NO");}
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Page properties -> `Navigation` -> `Warn on Unsaved Changes` set to `Yes`. After that it will work automatically. Works in APEX 5.

To cancel checks of unsaved changes, use JavaScript function `apex.page.cancelWarnOnUnsavedChanges();`. For example, if you save data with the DynamicAction, add additional true action with type `Execute JavaScript Code` and call it there.

Comment: I cant use that warn on unsaved changes. Because iam submitting the values in my page to the db through dynamic action(pl/sql code). So even after i saved the page and submitted, when i try to navigate to other page it will show warning on unsaved changes. I cant use submit page on click of save button as it is refreshing the whole page and it is not desired

Comment: It's possible to use the "Save before exit" APEX plugin to do this, but you'll need to read the accompanying documentation to work it out.

Comment: @dmitry But this doesnt solve my problem completely for i have asked for a way to define 'my_function' where in i can put various other functionalities ike a confirm message other than for unsaved changes!!